# Xcode: TableView cell layout changes on Click

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

`Cell` layout changes when i click on a cell
the Image on left hand side gets bigger...i don't know why

[image: This is the TableView]

[image: This is the Image After i click on a cell]

This is the Image After i click on a cell

Comment: can you post relevant code? By just looking at the screenshot, it's very hard to determine what's wrong.

Comment: this is happening when i design it...i havn't  done any code yet

Comment: the issue is may be in the layout constraints, because its look like one image is bigger and other one is short , also try setting aspect mode to aspect fit for UIImage

Comment: It is 100% about auto layout. You should show us your constraints.

Comment: my constraints are all objects pined to four sides,,,,image view have same width and labels have same height and same width

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[self.yourImage addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonIsPressed:)forControlEventTouchUpInside];


- (void) buttonIsPressed: (UIButton *) paramSender {

paramSender.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with AutoLayout
my outlet name was different then the Object name in storyboard
my outlet name was placeImage and my Object name in Storyboard was Image View...that created the problem